# Detect if a file is included in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In my posts, I sometimes include the same HTML pattern.
To do it so, I created `pattern.html` in `_includes/` and include it in my posts with :

```
{% include pattern.html %}
```

I would like to add a CSS file (or any other code) in my `header` if, and only if, `pattern.html` as been used in my post. To put it in pseudo-code, I would like to get the following `layouts/default.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      {% if pattern.html is included in the post %} code here {% endif %}
   </head>
   <body>
      {{ content }}
   </body>
</html>
```

I already tried to assign a variable in `pattern.html` and to test it in my layout, but this assignement occurs too late: the layout is already processed. I know I can pass a variable through YALM, but my objective is to get rid of it. I would prefer not to use plugins to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems asking the question helped me to answer it!
You can use the Liquid `contains` in order to look for a pattern in your post.

For example, if the included `pattern.html` contains a particular piece of code (`<!--pattern-->` for instance, or any particular HTML), you can use in your head:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      {% if content contains "<!--pattern-->" %} code here {% endif %}
   </head>
   <body>
  {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```

This can be used for any HTML pattern. For example, if you want to call the CSS file producing syntaxic coloration only if there is code in the page, use:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      {% if content contains "<code>" %}
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="code.css">
      {% endif %}
   </head>
   <body>
  {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```